# DROP TABLE command in dplyr

Tags: r, sqlite, dplyr

I am trying to remove a table from a database using dplyr in R.  In SQLite the way to do this is clear: DROP TABLE...however when I search for this command in the dplyr docs I find nothing and no suggestion that this command is available.  Is it?   How?

Comment: I suspect you'll need to send the `drop table` query directly to the database via a connection from RSQLite.

Comment: So I am coming from SAS and Access---have been using Python to wrangle the data, but still with SQLite...can you suggest R code to achieve this?

Comment: Actually, it turns out there is a `db_drop_table` function in **dplyr** that is exported, but not documented. Part of the general API, presumably. You'll still have to create a connection to the db yourself. How to do this is clearly documented in the RSQLite package, it's just one line.

Comment: If you want a clear answer, please provide reproductive code.

Answer (score 9):

As noted in the comments before, there are general database commands not really documented, among which ?db_drop_table.

To use it you need a connection object, this connection is attached to your database definition object:

```
pg <- src_postgres(dbname='NameOfDatabase', # Define the connection
                   user='user',
                   password='password')
> str(pg)
List of 3
 $ con  :Formal class 'PostgreSQLConnection' [package "RPostgreSQL"] with 1 slot
  .. ..@ Id: int [1:2] 12044 2
 $ info :List of 8
  ..$ host           : chr ""
  ..$ port           : chr "5432"
  ...
  ..$ rsId           : list()
 $ disco:<environment: 0x0000000011160fd8> 
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "src_postgres" "src_sql" "src"
```

So, in order to delete a table:

```
pg$con %>% db_drop_table(table='Tablename') # This drops the table 'Tablename'.
```

Comment: I use this all the time but I think with `pg$con` you are breaking encapsulation.  That is, the `con` field or slot could go away tomorrow, and you are not even supposed to know it's there. I develop a related package dplyr.spark and I was wondering how people would feel about having a SQL table removed when all the tbls that "point" to it are garbage collected. There would be a flag at tbl creation and a way to modify this (temporary). In this way, the remove command would just be "rm". If you change your mind once a tbl created, you could `persist` or `unpersist` a tbl.

Comment: The idea is to back normal concept and behaviors of R objects with equivalent concepts and behaviors of SQL objects, rather than piercing through the tbl abstraction with direct db access.